# Spring boot with IBM websphere application server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere

I am encountering issues while trying to use spring boot with a WAS(Websphere) server.
I have a webpage that accepts input and then executes @controller class.

Any help would be appreciated . Is that anything special we need to do in POM.xml for IBM websphere.

Below is my application class content.

```
    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{
    @Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); 
} }
```

I have added >packaging>war in my pom.xml

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 14 more
```

Spring-boot:run gives me below error trace.

```
    2016-01-13 16:03:05.331 ERROR 8004 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
    org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:23) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95) ~[na:1.7.0]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.7.0]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620) ~[na:2.6 (11-14-2014)]
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795) [na:1.7.0]
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
... 14 common frames omitted
    [WARNING] 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:795)
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException:         Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:23)
... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: 
    Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing   EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 14 more
    [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
     [INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And why would this be related to web sphere? You are trying to run the application from the command line for that it needs an embedded container. You need to add tomcat (or jetty or...) as  a provided dependency so that it is still available for running embedded but not used when deploying to web sphere. This is also explained in the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging)

Comment: I am trying to get it deployed in web sphere and see its running. If i open run administrative console for WAS and add the generated WAR(generated  from spring-boot:run) , the server startup logs shows my application started running. Is that the right way of adding war files to WAS from spring boot ?

Comment: `spring-boot:run` does create a package but also tries to run it. Just do `mvn clean package` or `install` this will also create the repackaged war. Then just deploy it to web sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WebSphere Liberty Starter application to create a Spring Boot application that will run on WebSphere Liberty:

http://liberty-starter.wasdev.developer.ibm.com

Just check the "Spring Boot with Spring MVC" and click Download Project.  The generate project will contain everything that you need to run a simple Spring Boot project on WebSphere Liberty:

- The Application class (the one you posted above looks correct already)
- The pom.xml file to include all the necessary SpringBoot dependencies (I suspect that you have something missing here).  It will also contain the necessary bits to create a WAR file and deploy it to WebSphere Liberty so that you can see it running straight away.
- There is also a generate example Spring MVC endpoint and test class so that you can see a running example.